# compute Average in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, average

**Problem Statement**

Given N integers, compute their average, correct to three decimal places.

**Input Format** 
The first line contains an integer N. 
This is followed by N integers, each on a new line.

**Output Format** 
Display the average of the N integers, rounded off to three decimal places.

**Input Constraints**

```
1 <= N <= 500 
-10000 <= x <= 10000 (x refers to elements of the list of integers for which the average is to be computed)
```

**Sample Input**

```
4
1
2
9
8
```

**Sample Output**

```
5.000
```

**explaination**

The '4' in the first line indicates that there are four integers whose average is to be computed. The average = (1 + 2 + 9 + 8)/4 = 20/4 = 5.000 (correct to three decimal places) Please include the zeroes even if they are redundant (eg. 0.000 instead of 0).

Comment: Good to know, what is the question?

Comment: [You'll need to show us what you have tried, and where you are exactly stuck](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'NR==1{n=$1;next} {s+=$1} END{printf "%.3f\n", s/n}' file
5.000
```