# How to find average and maximum in an interval using Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I would like to extract sum, mean and average in each 6 numbers interval from a column. 
I found many discussions related to this problem, but all those are for whole column. e.g.

To compute sum of a column:

```
awk '{sum+=$1} END { print sum}'
```

To calculate Average:

```
awk '{sum+=$1} END { print sum/NR}'
```

To find maximum or minimum, sort command can be used.

I need all these in an interval. e.g., my input file is

```
 inputfile.txt
 1     3
 2     5
 3     4
 4     3
 5     2
 6     1
 7     3
 8     3
 9     4
 10    2
 11    2
 12    2
 13    5
 14    4
 15    2
 16    3
 17    7
 18    3
```

Output files are

```
 sum.txt
 1   18
 2   16
 3   24

 average.txt
 1   3
 2   2.67
 3   4

 maximum.txt
 1   5
 2   4
 3   7
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [compute Average in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653995/compute-average-in-bash)

Comment: I take it that the first number is the line number and not anything in the file itself. You want to split the input file into parts of 6 numbers each, then output the sum, average, and maximum. Is that correct so far?

Comment: yes @chw21. You are correct. First column is serial number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make a search before you ask any question many posts are already there

You can try something like below, modify accordingly

**Input**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat input.txt 
1 3
2 5
3 4
4 3
5 2
6 1
7 3
8 3
9 4
10 2
11 2
12 2
13 5
14 4
15 2
16 3
17 7
18 3
```

**Script**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.awk
{
    sum += $2
    max  = max > $2 ? max : $2
}
!(FNR%6){
        print ++c,sum   > "sum.txt"
        print c,sum/6   > "average.txt"
        print c,max     > "maximum.txt"
        sum = max = ""
}
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk -f test.awk input.txt
```

**Sum**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat sum.txt 
1 18
2 16
3 24
```

**Average**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat average.txt 
1 3
2 2.66667
3 4
```

**Maximum**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat maximum.txt 
1 5
2 4
3 7
```

Comment: I was trying to find out minimum in same procedure, by adding    min  = min < $2 ? min : $2 . But not working. Can you please suggest, whether I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: try `min  = min!="" && min < $2 ? min : $2`

Answer (score 1):

This side isn't meant to write whole programs, and that's basically what you're asking us to do.

What you need to do is keep track of how many lines you've read and then every 6th line you produce output. Consider something like this:

```
awk '{sum += $1} (NR%6)==0 {print(sum); sum=0}' input.txt
```

I'm not going to explain what I did, because I expect you to please search the internet for `awk` tutorials, and get an understanding of what I am doing yourself.